# Find $o(2)$ in $U_n$ where $n = 2^{16} + 1$, $n$ is a prime number

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Find $o(2)$ in $U_n$ where $n = 2^{16} + 1$, $n$ is a prime number.

I have tried to use Euler's theorem to get $2^{2^{16}} = 1\pmod{2^{16}+1}$, but this is useless.

Since $o(2) \mid 2^{16}$,  $o(2) = 2^{k}$ for some $k$, but I was not able to go further.

Any help will be appericiated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$
2^{32}\equiv 1\bmod (2^{16}+1).
$$

Comment: How was I supposed to come up with this?

Comment: Well, $2^{16}\equiv -1\bmod 2^{16}+1$, right? So just square.